# Remove class method from an element

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, class

Hello I have a problem with this simple javascript

```
<script>   
 $(document).ready(function () {
 $(".submitBtn").click(function () {
     $(".erw").removeClass( "active" );
    });
 });</script>
```

I need to remove a particular class from the element that contains class erw while you click on element which has class submitBtn. Can someone help me and say why this doesnt work?

Comment: Is this a typo? sumitBtn

Comment: can you provide your html as well?

Comment: <div class="tab active"></div> and i need to change it to the <div class="tab"></div>

Comment: I did a quick js fiddle and it seems to work, http://jsfiddle.net/RkrLg/ Perhaps you could give us some more details about the code. Do you get any error in console?

Comment: Here is an updated fiddle, to demonstrate that the class is being removed.. http://jsfiddle.net/RkrLg/2/

Comment: Oh yes, I am not using buttons but <a></a>, there is just simple <a data="tabname" class="submitBtn">Tab</a> and then <div tab="tabname" class="tab active"></div>

Answer (score 0):

From your html

```
<div class="tab active"></div>
```

it seems the code should look like:

```
$(".tab.active").removeClass( "active" );
```